# Mongo Query array, when array key is unknown?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have following in the database,
and I like to find this item with a the search term "open"

It should almost be something like this, I guess???

> ```
>  $query = array(array('keywords' => array('$in'=>'open')));
>  $cursor = $collection->find($query);
>  return iterator_to_array($cursor);
> ```

**In Database:**

```
[3b33162ad4ed5ffdeb88a1b2085535b1] => Array
    (
        [_id] => 3b33162ad4ed5ffdeb88a1b2085535b1
        [title] => Something
        [keywords] => Array
            (
                [2] => open
                [7] => source
            )

        [added] => MongoDate Object
            (
                [sec] => 1305884144
                [usec] => 658000
            )

    )
```

Comment: And the question is? What is the problem?  And why a nested array(...)?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having is the structure of your data.

MongoDB natively works with arrays when querying. The following will work.

```
$document = array( 'keywords' => array('open', 'source') );
$collection->insert($document);
$collection->find( array('keywords' => 'open') );
```

The problem you have is that `keywords` is not an array in your document. In your document `keywords` is another document.

```
'keywords' => array( '2' => 'open',
                     '7' => 'source' )
```

In JSON this would look like this:

```
{ 'keywords' : { '2': 'open', '7': 'source' } };
```

Based on what you're trying to do you need to save keywords as an array and not as a hashtable.

In PHP it's not always obvious which you're dealing with at code time. However, if you `print_r` an array, it will look like the following. Notice the array is zero-based and is not missing any keys.

```
    [keywords] => Array
        (
            [0] => open
            [1] => source
            [2] => rules
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query Arrays in MongoDB like normal values. Here an example in the JavaScript Shell.

```
> db.php.insert({title: "something", keywords: ["foo","bar"]})
> db.php.insert({title: "something", keywords: ["open","bar"]})
> db.php.insert({title: "something", keywords: ["baz","faz"]})
> db.php.find({ keywords: "open" });
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4dd677229a547d85bb02fce5"), "title" : "something", "keywords" : [ "open", "bar" ] }
```

For Faster Queries you should create an index on the array.

> db.php.ensureIndex({keywords: 1})

Comment: What has this to do with the PHP specific question?

Comment: He didn't knew how to query the keywords fields. I showed him in the JavaScript Shell how he can do it. He just needs to translate the Query to PHP. Probably it is: $query = array("keywords" => "open").

Comment: I don't get it! I still don't know how to query something if the key is unknown.